# MomgoTemplate alike function not working as expected

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongotemplate

I am using MongoTemplate in SpringBoot application to access the data.
I have to query to DB and I am using "Criteria" object to create a query.

I want to write a query which search data using "alike" funciton.

```
Query query = new Query();        
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
criterias.add(Criteria.where(DATA).alike(Example.of(text)));
criterias.add(Criteria.where(POST).alike(Example.of(text)));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(criterias));
```

When the code runs it fails and showing the error like:
[image]

Dont know what the issue is.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used is replace "alike" function with "regex" and make necessary changes to run the code.

There is bug in the "alike" function. (I debug the code)

Atul